# I need to send response from graphene query. The problem is the response should contain particular fields only based on role of the user

Tags: python, graphene-python, graphene-django

For Example:
If the user is member of the group, response would contain all the group information including members of the group, else response will only contain the count of members in group.
I'm using graphene-django and need to return this data from a query schema.

```
class GroupMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    group = graphene.Field(GroupType)

    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.ID(required=False)
        created_by = graphene.ID(required=False) 
        admins = graphene.ID(required=False)
        moderators = graphene.ID(required=False)
        users = graphene.List(graphene.ID)
        name = graphene.String(required = True)
        public = graphene.Boolean(required=False)
        location = graphene.String(required=False)
        reported = graphene.Boolean(required=False)
        reported_by = graphene.List(graphene.ID)
        profile_picture = Upload(required=False)
        background_picture = Upload(required=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GraphQL/Graphene *schema* will need to contain both fields, since the schema cannot conditionally change depending on the user, but you can conditionally choose to *populate* those fields in the response based on what the user should access.

For example:

```py
import graphene

class GroupNode(graphene.ObjectType):
    # Assume MemberNode is defined elsewhere
    members = graphene.List(MemberNode) 
    members_count = graphene.Int()

    def resolve_members(parent, info):
        if info.context.user.username == 'allowed_user':
            return Members.objects.all() # whatever logic you need
        # Return nothing if the user is not allowed
        return None

    def resolve_members_count(parent, info):
        if info.context.user.username == 'allowed_user':
            # We don't need to return this, since the user can access `members` directly
            return None
        return Members.objects.count()
```

Note that both fields will need to be nullable (i.e. you can't pass `required=True`), so that you can optionally choose to omit them in the `resolve_` methids. (Alternatively, you could choose to make `members` non-null with `required=True`, and `return []` rather than `return None`, if that's more convenient.)

There are also some other types of [authorization examples Graphene-Django docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/authorization/), in case those are helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is helpful. I have a query though. Can I get pk of Group in resolve_members function because I need to check if the user is member in this group?

Comment: If you're using `DjangoObjectType` (https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/#queries-objecttypes) rather than `graphene.ObjectType`, the `parent` argument in the `resolve` methods above will be the `Group` object, so you could obtain the `pk` via `parent.pk`. You'd have the query definition as something like `class Query(graphene.ObjectType):  group_by_id = graphene.Field(GroupNode, id=graphene.String())` as in the example in the Graphene-Django docs.